# RandomReal vs Random[Real

Tags: random, implementation-details, function-comparison

Let's say I need random numbers with increasing precision to simulate a particular function, so I try:

```
Table[SeedRandom[1]; 
  RandomReal[{0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> i], {i, 1, 20}] // TableForm
```

[image]

While I was experimenting with this, I checked docs for `Random` and tried the following variation.

```
Table[SeedRandom[1]; Random[Real, {0, 1}, i], {i, 1, 20}] // TableForm
```

[image]

---

**Question(s)**

1- For my own learning, I was wondering if someone could please explain the difference.

2- How was something like this done prior to v6.0?

3- Or am I comparing apples with oranges?

4- With the same `SeedRandom`, why are different random numbers being generated for the 2nd case as the precision changes?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Probably a different algorithm is used for Random and RandomReal

Comment: The change with precision between 19 and 20 is a hint that it switched from a 64 bit unsigned integer method to a different algorithm. `Log[10, 2.^64]` is `19.2659`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I reproduce this behavior with versions 5.2, 8.0.4, 12.3.1, and 13.0.0 on Windows 10 x64:

[image: screenshot]

As you see, before version 6 the behavior of `Random` was exactly the same.

I guess that peculiarities like this were the main reason why `Random` was superseded by the functions `RandomReal` and `RandomInteger` in version 6.0. Apparently, `Random` is kept only for backward compatibility purposes. All usage examples for `Random` were removed from the Documentation in version 6. Here is how its page looked in Mathematica Help Browser of version 5.2:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

I. Earlier one might have controlled precision with `SetPrecision`.

Either generate a random number with higher precision than needed and lower the precision:

```
Table[SeedRandom[1]; 
 SetPrecision[Random[Real, {0, 1}, 100], i], {i, 1, 20}]
```

Or set the precision of a machine-precision number:

```
Table[SeedRandom[1]; 
 SetPrecision[Random[Real, {0, 1}], i], {i, 1, 20}]
```

II. The legacy algorithm of `Random[]` is available for `RandomReal[]` and kin via the `Method` option in `SeedRandom`.

```
SeedRandom[1, Method -> "Legacy"];
RandomReal[]
```

generates the same sequence of random reals as

```
SeedRandom[1, Method -> "Legacy"];
Random[Real]
```

This reproduces the OP's `Random[Real...]` table:

```
SeedRandom[Method -> "Legacy"];
Table[SeedRandom[1]; 
  RandomReal[{0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> i], {i, 1, 20}] // TableForm
```